# asp.net send parts of aspx page to email

Tags: asp.net, html, viewstate, code-behind

I have an ASPX Page

```
<h1 class="TitleClass" >Title</h1>

<p> some stuff </p>
<p> some stuff </p>

<div class="ContentClass" > Content </div>
```

I want to send an email with some parts of this ASPX file:
I only want to send the h1 and div as html as an email, how do I go about achieving this from code behind?

Comment: A larger issue you will face for this requirement is including the css styles (TitleClass & ContentClass) which, I assume, are defined in an external css file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a template for your email(it would be the easiest) like take the parts you want to send:

```
string message=@"<h1 class='TitleClass' >Title</h1>
                 <div class='ContentClass' > Content </div>";
```

Try this:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, message);
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
client.Send(mail);
```

Note that I set the mail message html to true: **mail.IsBodyHtml = true;** and send your html in `message`.

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't exactly my problem, I want to send only the h1 and div elements with their style to the email not the entire page.